# SQL Server inside a docker container on Linux: Login from outside not possible

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have here a SQL Server Docker container. I have created the container with this command:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=SA.123456" -u 0:0 -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 --hostname sql1 -d    mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
```

I can start the container

```
docker start sql1
```

and I can open a SQL console inside of the container:

```
docker exec -it sql1 "bash"

root@sql1:/# /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1,1433 -U SA
Password:
```

So far, so good. But I want to open a SQL console from outside the container. To do that I run `sqlcmd` from my linux machine directly, but I get following error:

```
/> /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1,1433 -U SA
Password:
```

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Timeout error [258].
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Unable to complete login process due to delay in prelogin response.

If I try to connect to 127.0.0.1:1433 I get a connection (and I have also checked that the connection is refused if I stop the container)

```
/> telnet 127.0.0.1 1433
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

So I'm sure that the connection by self can be established. But why I get the error "Unable to complete login process due to delay in prelogin response."?

Comment: What specific version of ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server do you have? Microsoft hasn't updated the [SQL version compatibility matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files#sql-version-compatibility) to include SQL Server 2022 yet. Given [Supported operating systems matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files#supported-operating-systems) shows Windows Server 2022 requires 17.9 I wouldn't be surprised if there's a similar requirement for SQL Server 2022.

Comment: Note also that ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server added support for TDS 8.0.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: Maybe you are right. I think my mistake was to use the https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod repository on Linux Mint 21 (which is based on Ubuntu 22). Today I could not remove, update or reinstall the mssql-tools and *odbc* packages (due to dependency errors). I had to remove all packages manually with ```dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq ...```. I think on Ubuntu 22 based systems the MSSQL stuff is currently unusable.... :-( . I will now with qemu/kvm install a virtual Linux Mint 20 (based on Ubuntu 20) and install there the MS SQL stuff